# display: inline-block creates bar on the bottom of the li

Tags: html, css, text-align

I'm developing a web site to display services of a company, the problem is that suddenly when i was coding other section of the site a bar appeared on my second menu, to select categories, that's crazy

here's the page [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9Xm8k/2/)

```
<div class="menu2">
<div class="aux_960">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">saf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">saf</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">saf</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

It's right on the bottom of the :after pseudo-element of the li, on the second menu where we have three "saf" links

I tried to solve this, but nothing that i do seems to help it anyway, the only thing that removed the bar was setting the li positioning to float:left, but that dont feels right

on this fiddle the images dont show up of course, but you guys should be able to see the bar

thanks!!

Comment: Please edit to add the CSS you're using, and preferably try to recreate the problem on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: the problem is there, i cant recreate the entire page because of the images, i cant either post the link because its numeric, but the problem is there, when i put only the menu, the problem is solved, but i need it working on the full page

Comment: here's the [link](http://192.163.244.148/~modertec/produtos.html)

Comment: @SlightlyCuban the link is a jsfiddle link. I simplified the code here http://jsfiddle.net/9Xm8k/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from

```
.menu2 {
    display: block;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Remove `text-decoration: underline;`

This blocks is lower in the code you have, there are 2 definitions of `.menu2` this is in the second one

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/9Xm8k/8/

Here is the fix in your original code http://jsfiddle.net/9Xm8k/9/

Answer (score 0):

[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Xm8k/4/)

```
.menu
{
    background: #d1d1d1;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: i dont see any difference from my original page, sorry

Comment: Your left and right side of the header are floated left and right respectively. So, you need to clear float for the element right after it, here it is your menu. So, clear:both, should resolve your problem.